# Annotations using annotator.js is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, node.js, annotations

I am using annotator.js and store range in **mysql**. For Highlight text i am using this code on my code file.

```
<script src="/js/pdfjs/annotator.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function(){

  var annotation = $('#content').annotator();

  annotation.annotator('addPlugin', 'Store', {
  prefix: '',
    urls: {
        create:  '/highlighter',
        update:  '/update/:id',
        destroy: '/delete/:id',
        search:  '/highlightersearch'
    }
  });
var comments = {
  "total": 1, 
  "rows": [
    {
      "text": "n thi", 
      "consumer": "d4c108122b51434aab1d27ad4ebd2b02", 
      "permissions": {
        "update": [], 
        "read": [], 
        "admin": [], 
        "delete": []
      }, 
      "updated": "2017-04-07T10:31:55.378772+00:00", 
      "quote": "ffff", 
      "uri": "http://localhost:8124/user/pdf/14396734926770", 
      "id": "AVtH-G9LqWiVDsXRg1jq", 
      "ranges": [
        {
          "endOffset": 6, 
          "startOffset": 1, 
          "end": "/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]", 
          "start": "/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]"
        }
      ], 
      "created": "2017-04-07T10:31:55.378759+00:00"
    }]};

var arr = $.map(comments, function(el) { return el });
annotation.annotator("loadAnnotations", arr);  

});
</script>
```

Error:
I am getting this on console log "**TypeError: _ref1 is undefined**"
Any idea what i am doing wrong, please help me to shortcut  this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using this request,

annotation.annotator('addPlugin', 'Store', {
        prefix: prefixUrl,
          annotationData: {
            'uri': '/annotations'
          },

Thanks